# GETLINE not properly working in awk script

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

I have troubles in treating a file with awk, in terms of properly having the parser to step to the next line. The GETLINE directive of the awk utility doesn't seem to function in my awk treatment session.

The input file has 7 categories of lines:

- the Section Identifier,
- the Section Title,
- the Chapter identifier,
- the Chapter title,
- the delivery timestamp,
- the age of the record,
- the label of the record

Here is a sample:

```
Section 2                                                              Line 0001
Setup The Java IDE                                                     Line 0002
9.                                                                     Line 0003
How To Install The Java Development Kit (JDK) For Ubuntu Linux         Line 0004
0:12                                                                   Line 0005
2 months ago                                                           Line 0006
Installation of the JDK on Linux                                       Line 0007
0:49                                                                   Line 0008
2 months ago                                                           Line 0009
APT-GET update - first run                                             Line 0010
1:12                                                                   Line 0011
2 months ago                                                           Line 0012
Adding the WEBUP8TEAM repository                                       Line 0013
1:37                                                                   Line 0014
2 months ago                                                           Line 0015
APT-GET update - second run                                            Line 0016
2:01                                                                   Line 0017
2 months ago                                                           Line 0018
```

Within the input file there are a few sections, each of them containing several chapters. Each chapter in turn has tens of records, which are characterized by delivery timestamp, age, and label.

My script uses a six-step sequence, each of them trying to identify the right kind of line, and printing them, by actually skipping the delivery timestamp, and the age, and by merging the chapter and section identifiers with their associated titles in single lines.

The awk code is this:

```
BEGIN { FoundNewSection = 0
    FoundChapterLN = 0
    TimeStampLN = 0
    PrefixString = "000"
      }

  FoundNewSection==1 { TimeStampLN = 0
           FoundNewSection = 0
              PrefixString = ""
     print "\n   Print Line (" $NF "), " PrefixString "    New Section Printed, no NEXT called"
             }

  FoundChapterLN==1  { TimeStampLN = 0
            FoundChapterLN = 0
              PrefixString = ""
      print "\n   Print Line (" $NF ") " PrefixString "   New Chapter Printed, no NEXT called"
             }

  $1=="Section"      { TimeStampLN = 0
           FoundNewSection = 1
              PrefixString = $1
      print "No Print Line (" $NF ") new Section detected, NEXT called"
      GETLINE
      NEXT
             }

  $1 ~ /^([0-9])+\./ { FoundChapterLN = 1
             PrefixString = $1
      print "No Print Line (" $NF ") new Chapther detected, NEXT called"
      GETLINE
      NEXT
             }

  $3=="ago" || $4=="ago" || /^([0-9])+:([0-9])+/ { TimeStampLN = 1
      print "No Print Line (" $NF ") TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called"
      GETLINE
      NEXT
                         }


  FoundNewSection == 0 && FoundChapterLN == 0 {
      print "   Print Line (" $NF  ") is normal Line"
                      }

END { print "END : " NR }
```

It is supposed to effectively end up the current row processing whenever it identifies the type of line (tests in lines 19, 27 and 34), and go for the next row. I thought that "GETLINE;NEXT" pair of commands would do it, but it seems I'm wrong.

After a first test, I found that despite the "GETLINE;NEXT" instructions, the awk actually doesn't go on skipping to the next line, but rather continue working on the same line, until it ends up the whole script. That gives me this output

```
<Blank LIne>
No Print Line (0001) new Section detected, NEXT called
<Blank LIne>
   Print Line (0002),     New Section Printed, no NEXT called
   Print Line (0002) is normal Line
No Print Line (0003) new Chapther detected, NEXT called
<Blank LIne>
   Print Line (0004)    New Chapter Printed, no NEXT called
   Print Line (0004) is normal Line
No Print Line (0005) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
   Print Line (0005) is normal Line
No Print Line (0006) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
   Print Line (0006) is normal Line
   Print Line (0007) is normal Line
No Print Line (0008) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
   Print Line (0008) is normal Line
No Print Line (0009) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
   Print Line (0009) is normal Line
   Print Line (0010) is normal Line
No Print Line (0011) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
   Print Line (0011) is normal Line
No Print Line (0012) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
   Print Line (0012) is normal Line
   Print Line (0013) is normal Line
No Print Line (0014) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
   Print Line (0014) is normal Line
No Print Line (0015) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
   Print Line (0015) is normal Line
   Print Line (0016) is normal Line
No Print Line (0017) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
   Print Line (0017) is normal Line
No Print Line (0018) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
   Print Line (0018) is normal Line
```

instead of this one

```
<Blank LIne>
No Print Line (0001) new Section detected, NEXT called
<Blank LIne>
   Print Line (0002),     New Section Printed, no NEXT called
No Print Line (0003) new Chapther detected, NEXT called
<Blank LIne>
   Print Line (0004)    New Chapter Printed, no NEXT called
No Print Line (0005) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
No Print Line (0006) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
   Print Line (0007) is normal Line
No Print Line (0008) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
No Print Line (0009) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
   Print Line (0010) is normal Line
No Print Line (0011) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
No Print Line (0012) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
   Print Line (0013) is normal Line
No Print Line (0014) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
No Print Line (0015) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
   Print Line (0016) is normal Line
No Print Line (0017) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
No Print Line (0018) TimeStamp Line detected, NEXT called
```

It actually seems that despite the "GETLINE;NEXT" it still uses the contents of the current line and the rest of the awk code for the same line.

Am I doing something wrong with the "GETLINE;NEXT" commands ?

Comment: To answer your immediate question, it's `getline` and `next`, lower case, which is different than the upper case versions you have in your code (you've simply entered variables that have no value, hence do nothing as you've seen). Having said that, no doubt you'll get some advice on how to avoid `getline` altogether, as it's rarely the best way of going about things in awk.

Comment: Removing `getline` (and switch to lowercase `next`) gives the result desired. You don't need getline, because the actions defined between `BEGIN` and `END` are already executed for each input line. `getline`'s main intention is to get content from additional files.

Comment: Problem solved by using lowercase, and inserting some new `code`next`code` after the "New section/chapter" printing lines. Thank you, guys !